# Iterating through object Where Value is Array of Objects and return one value from each Objects of Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to get all the `office` values from this and store it as a simple array?

```
var data = {
  'XYZ': [{
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'open',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29'
    },
    {
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'processed',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32'
    }
  ],
  'yyy': [{
      office: 'yyy.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'delivered',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29'
    },
    {
      office: 'yyy.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'open',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32'
    }
  ],
  'zzz': [{
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'delivered',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29'
    },
    {
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'open',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32'
    }
  ]
}
```

The output should be like:

```
officesArray = ['xyz.in', 'yyy.in', 'xyz.in']
```

my code is

```
var Office = (Object.entries(grpDatas).flatMap(([k, v]) => (v.forEach(({office})=> office))))
```

It prints `array of undefined`.

Comment: i have edited the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: why is `'xyz.in'` twice in the result set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `forEach` and also you're accessing `email` instead of `office`:

```js
var data = {
  'XYZ': [{
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'open',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29'
    },
    {
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'processed',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32'
    }
  ],
  'yyy': [{
      office: 'yyy.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'delivered',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29'
    },
    {
      office: 'yyy.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'open',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32'
    }
  ],
  'zzz': [{
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'delivered',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29'
    },
    {
      office: 'xyz.in',
      reportName: 'payroll',
      event: 'open',
      timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32'
    }
  ]
}

var Email = Object.values(data).flatMap(item => [...new Set(item.map(({office})=> office))])
console.log(Email)
```

Comment: i want the output in this way ['xyz.in','yyy.in','xyz.in'] i have used your way.

Comment: Actually, `Object.entries` isn't even necessary here, `Object.values` will be enough.

Comment: but it returns 2 times i want only time each value of the office.

Comment: @Amar then you need to use `Set` on the inner map to remove duplicates. I've updated the answer.

Comment: is it possible to filter the timestamp and get the timestamp according to that event and store it into the array ?

Comment: @Amar instead of returning just `office`, you'll need to return office and timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You could get unique values from the wanted properties.

```js
var data = { XYZ: [{ office: 'xyz.in', reportName: 'payroll', event: 'open', timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29' }, { office: 'xyz.in', reportName: 'payroll', event: 'processed', timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32' }], yyy: [{ office: 'yyy.in', reportName: 'payroll', event: 'delivered', timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29' }, { office: 'yyy.in', reportName: 'payroll', event: 'open', timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32' }], zzz: [{ office: 'xyz.in', reportName: 'payroll', event: 'delivered', timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:29' }, { office: 'xyz.in', reportName: 'payroll', event: 'open', timestamp: '02-12-2019 00:15:32' }] },
    office = Object.values(data).flatMap(v => [...new Set(v.map(({ office }) => office))]);

console.log(office);
```

Answer (score 0):

`const result = Object.keys(data)
     .map( key => data[key])
     .flat()
     .map( element => element.office)`

Transforming everything to arrays and flattening them helps a lot!

https://codepen.io/t0dorakis/pen/MWYerKL